# Print "\x09", print 0x20, how to print 0x09 to STDOUT?

Tags: python, bash, perl

I try to print to STDOUT the 0x09 (horizontal TAB) value, but in perl, python or bash 0x09 is replaced by 0x20 (a space).

```
$ hexdump -C <<< $(perl -e 'print "A\x09B" ')
00000000  41 20 42 0a                                       |A B.|
00000004
```

same problem in bash:

```
$ hexdump -C <<< $(printf "A\x09B")
00000000  41 20 42 0a                                       |A B.|
00000004
```

It's possible to print the 0x09 value to STDOUT?

Comment: `perl -e 'print "A\x09B"'` outputs tab for me, I can see it on screen and see it in file if I redirect output

Comment: `echo -e "foo\x09bar"`

Comment: So at issue here is the `<<<` operator, using a pipe shows a tab.

Comment: Quoting: `hexdump -C <<< "$(printf 'A\x09B')"`

Comment: Always quote parameter expansions, unless you explicitly want word-splitting... which you generally _don't_ want. See [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Quoting) for details.

Comment: @Cyrus: It's not clear what your comment means. It is an exact copy of the last line of code in the question, and the OP says it produces a space character as before

Comment: @Borodin no, it is not exact copy.

Comment: What output do you expect ?

Comment: @Borodin: Cyrus's code protects the `$(...)` command with double-quotes.

Comment: @PM2Ring According to the `bash` documentation, the argument to `<<<` isn't supposed to undergo word-splitting, but command substitutions still incorrectly do. This is fixed in 4.4.

Comment: Thanks, @chepner. Still, "when in doubt, double-quote" is a good motto when doing stuff with Bash parameter expansions. :)

Comment: @PM2Ring: Ah, I apologise. Cyrus' *original* comment was identical to the OP's code. I am using the SO tablet app which doesn't update comments when they are modified

Comment: @Borodin: That's correct.

Comment: @Alik: You could have helped a lot by describing the difference

Comment: @Borodin: Mystery solved! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's entirely a bash issue. Specifically, it's a bash bug that can be worked around as follows:

```
                 +-------- Add these ---------+
                 |                            |
                 v                            v
$ hexdump -C <<< "$(perl -e 'print "A\x09B"' )"
00000000  41 09 42 0a                                       |A.B.|
00000004
```

Alternatively,

```
# Passed via STDIN as the original.
$ perl -e 'print "A\x09B"' | hexdump -C
00000000  41 09 42                                          |A.B|
00000003

# Passed via a file name.
$ hexdump -C <( perl -e 'print "A\x09B"' )
00000000  41 09 42                                          |A.B|
00000003
```

Comment: Note the quotes *shouldn't* be necessary, but are until `bash` 4.4 is released. (The man page states that the word following `<<<` isn't subject to word-splitting; the shell itself is still striving to reach that goal :)

Comment: @chepner i think quotes should be necessary (even it is being changed so they aren't) as it isn't a single word after the "<<<" as the subshell would be processed first and so there would be multiple words. If it is being changed to no quotes, does that mean that `cat <<< 1 2 3 54 5` should work? what about newlines ? etc

Comment: @chepner Do you know when the bashref was updated to indicate which expansions take place on the heredoc "word"?

Comment: Good question; sometime after 4.1, at least by 4.3 (I don't have 4.2 to check)

Comment: `cat <<< 1 2 3 54 5` doesn't involve word-splitting; that's simply parsing, so `1` is the only word used by `<<<`; the rest are ordinary arguments to `cat`. By contrast, `$(...)` is a single word whose expansion may be subject to word-splitting, depending on context.

Comment: Similar problems for ordinary parameters expansions were fixed in 4.3, but command substitutions seem to be handled by separate code, so they slipped through.

Answer (score 8):

At issue here is Bash *expansion*; you get the same issue with putting the command in backticks:

```bash
$ echo `python -c 'print "A\x09B"'`
A B
```

Avoid expansion; it splits your input on whitespace and rejoins for the next command; you see the same with multiple spaces:

```bash
$ hexdump -C <<< $(python -c 'print "A\x20\x20\x20B"')
00000000  41 20 42 0a                                       |A B.|
00000004
```

Use a pipe instead:

```bash
$ python -c 'print "A\x09B"' | hexdump
0000000 41 09 42 0a
0000004
```

or quote the command (miraculously, the extra quotes don't clash with those used in the command line itself!):

```bash
hexdump -C <<< "$(python -c 'print "A\x20\x20\x20B"')"
```

The subprocess output being expanded is a bug in bash, to be fixed in bash 4.4.

Comment: Technically, this is a bug in `bash`. The argument following `<<<` isn't supposed to undergo word-splitting, but command substitutions do. This is fixed in the upcoming 4.4 release. Quoting the expansion will also solve the problem.

Comment: @chepner: ah, interesting, I already had trouble justifying the behaviour from the man page..